# Spring 3.0 exception converting String to java.util.Date on POST

Tags: json, spring, date, smartgwt, java.util.date

I'm hoping someone can help me since I have been banging my head against a wall for a couple of days on a issue which seems straightforward and which has been documented in other threads on the web.

I am using Smart GWT client (3.0) in conjunction with Spring 3.1 server and using JSON to communicate (with Jackson API 1.9).

The issue is that when I attempt to save a date from my SmartGWT client and it is sent to the server I get the following exception:

`org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'comment' on field 'dateAdded': rejected value [2012-06-27T10:57:47+0100]; codes [typeMismatch.comment.dateAdded,typeMismatch.dateAdded,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [comment.dateAdded,dateAdded]; arguments []; default message [dateAdded]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'dateAdded'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type java.util.Date for value '2012-06-27T10:57:47+0100'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:110)`

I have seen this issue in a few other posts, but most relate to not having formatted the Date in the correct format, but I have tried various formats: 
- yyyy-MM-dd
- yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
- yyyyMMddHHmmssZ (as per suggestion here: http://code.google.com/p/usersapi/issues/detail?id=8)

So in my code I have done the following:

1. Configured a CustomObjectMapper:

`
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

public CustomObjectMapper() {
    super();
    configure(Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    setDateFormat(formatter);
    getDeserializationConfig().setDateFormat(formatter);
}
```

}
`

1. Spring app context thusly:

`

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>            
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
            <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/xml"/>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.jpmorgan.creditriskreporting.server" />

<bean id="marshallingConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
    <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/xml"/>
</bean>


<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
    <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
</bean>


<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.jpmorgan.creditriskreporting.server.util.CustomObjectMapper" />


<!-- Client -->
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="marshallingConverter" />
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

`

1. Bean object:

`
import java.util.Date;

@JsonAutoDetect
public class Comment {

```
private int id;
private String comment;
private Date dateAdded;

public Comment() {}

public Comment(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

...

```
//@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class) -- I had previously tried to use these custom Date serializer class
public Date getDateAdded() {
    return dateAdded;
}
//@JsonDeserialize(using=JsonDateDeserializer.class)
public void setDateAdded(Date dateAdded) {
    this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
}
```

`

**EDIT:**

1. Controller Class

This may be where the issue lies, since when I use @RequestBody it works from my Integration tests, however, my Abstract RestDataSource in SmartGWT only works with @ModelAttribute, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

`@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Comment createNewComment2(@ModelAttribute Comment comment) {
        log.info("calling createComment with comment: {}", comment);
        comment.setDateAdded(new Date());
        Comment added = commentDao.create(comment);
        log.info("created comment: {}", added);
        return commentDao.get(comment);

    }`

So I can fetch data from the server and the date is displayed in SmartGWT fine. It's only when I do the add data that I get the issue. From Smart GWT Developer Console:

`{
    "dataSource":"CommentDS", 
    "operationType":"add", 
    "componentId":"isc_DynamicForm_1", 
    "data":{
        "userAdded":"sharper", 
        "dateAdded":"2012-06-27T10:57:47+0100", 
        "comment":"sample"
    }, 
    "callback":{
        "target":[DynamicForm ID:isc_DynamicForm_1], 
        "methodName":"saveEditorReply"
    }, 
    "showPrompt":true, 
    "prompt":"Saving form...", 
    "oldValues":{
    }, 
    "clientContext":{
    }, 
    "requestId":"CommentDS$6272"
}`

Any help with this is hugely appreciated.

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found out the issue thanks to http://vkubushyn.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/smart-gwt-restful-spring-mvc

Had to use Spring's InitBinder

`@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
    }`

Answer (score 7):

You should add DateFormat into your model.

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
private Date beginDate;
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
private Date endDate;
```

as a function parameter

```
 void  functionName** (@RequestParam("beginDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")Date beginDate, @RequestParam("endDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")Date endDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but as far as I remember the Z stands for timezone in ISOwhoknowswhatformat. And that's 4 chars wide, so I would try this:

> new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ");

By the way: if this is the issue you should've catched it in your unit tests. You do have unit test for `CustomObjectMapper` don't you? :P

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried updating to the format yo suggested, but I get the same exception:

`org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'comment' on field 'dateAdded': rejected value [2012-06-27T12:39:40GMT+01:00]; `

So it's not valid either.

Comment: Create a unit test and try to manually parse data, then tell spring to do it. You would surely catch the error with some debugging.